# All LESS files are not getting compiled

Tags: css, gulp, less, gulp-minify-css

How to get base.less minified file compiled in gulp and import it in main.ts

Comment: are you using angular-cli ? gulp ? webpack ?

Comment: i am using webpack

Comment: are you using webstorm?

Comment: no , i dont use that